# ActionView::MissingTemplate: ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template /members with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, tdd

An integration test is returning a 'Missing Template' error.  The `microposts_interface_test.rb` errors on `/members`.  It may be because the /members view uses the MicropostsController but I'm unsure how to fix the test.

```
ERROR["test_micropost_interface", MicropostsInterfaceTest, 2015-06-19 06:40:32 +0800]
 test_micropost_interface#MicropostsInterfaceTest (1434667232.75s)
ActionView::MissingTemplate:         ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template /members with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
          * "/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
          * "/home/me/Development/my_app/app/views"
          * "/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
          * "/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/phrasing-4.0.0rc9/app/views"

            app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:14:in `create'
            test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MicropostsInterfaceTest>'
            test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:MicropostsInterfaceTest>'
        app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:14:in `create'
        test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MicropostsInterfaceTest>'
        test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:MicropostsInterfaceTest>'
```

MicropostsInterfaceTest:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MicropostsInterfaceTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "micropost interface" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get members_path
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    assert_select 'input[type=file]'
    # Invalid submission
    assert_no_difference 'Micropost.count' do
      post microposts_path, micropost: { content: "" }
    end
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Valid submission
    content = "This micropost really ties the room together"
    picture = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/rails.png', 'image/png')
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', 1 do
      post microposts_path, micropost: { content: content, picture: picture }
    end
    assert assigns(:micropost).picture?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_match content, response.body
    # Delete a post.
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete'
    first_micropost = @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).first
    assert_difference 'Micropost.count', -1 do
      delete micropost_path(first_micropost)
    end
    # Visit a different user.
    get user_path(users(:archer))
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end

  test "micropost sidebar count" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get members_path
    assert_match "#{@user.microposts.count} microposts", response.body
    # User with zero microposts
    other_user = users(:mallory)
    log_in_as(other_user)
    get members_path
    assert_match "0 microposts", response.body
    # Create a micropost.
    other_user.microposts.create!(content: "A micropost")
    get members_path
    assert_match "1 micropost", response.body
  end
end
```

**Update:**

```
# controller/members_controller.rb

class MembersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :logged_in_user
  def index
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

I confirm there is a specific index view at `app/views/members/index.html.erb`.

**Update 2:**

```
# controller/microposts_controller.rb

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to members_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render members_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || members_path
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to members_path if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your action methods code for that specific url?
Also can you ensure that specific action methods has a action view file ?

Comment: Can you post you microposts controller ?

Comment: @LuisMenjivar, I have added the MicropostsController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the create action in the MicropostController use `render "members/index"` instead of `render members_path`. Note that render does not load the variables needed in members/index, it only loads the template so add `@micropost = []` just like you did for `@feed_items = []` so that if you are calling those variables from the view you don't get an error of can't find variable @microposts. Or you can simply `redirect_to members_path`.

Answer (score 0):

It was useful for me:

```
render template: 'template', formats: [:html]
```